# Alter all table's - discard tablespace

Tags: mysql

After having an awful experience with a dedicated server and spending 3 whole days repairing corrupted databases (Yes I know.... backup!).... I have narrowed the issues down to a few websites. The trouble is, these websites are Magento websites.

I am having to import the .ibd files into the /var/lib/mysql folder and DISCARD/IMPORT the tablespace.

Is there a way to alter ALL tables in the database at once, i.e `ALTER TABLE * DISCARD TABLESPACE` and then move the files across... Then `ALTER TABLE * IMPORT TABLESPACE` ?

Answer (score 1):

Not as part of MySQL, but tools like Percona Xtrabackup makes the process a bit faster for exporting/backing up the tables, allowing things like using regular expressions or lists for filtering:

- [Partial backups](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/innobackupex/partial_backups_innobackupex.html)
- [Restoring individual tables](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/innobackupex/restoring_individual_tables_ibk.html)

For importing a list of tables, you can use some automation oneliners like [this one found on Bill Karwin tools](https://github.com/billkarwin/bk-tools/blob/master/xtraimport):

```
mysqldump --no-data $schema > schema-ddl.sql
mysql -N -B <<'EOF' > discard-ddl.sql
SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE `', table_name, '` DISCARD TABLESPACE;') AS _ddl
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='$schema' AND ENGINE='InnoDB';
EOF
mysql -N -B <<'EOF' > import-ddl.sql
SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE `', table_name, '` IMPORT TABLESPACE;') AS _ddl
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='$schema' AND ENGINE='InnoDB';
EOF
```

Basically, you can use the `information_schema.tables` table for listing the tables you want using "dynamic sql". For example, change `$schema` above for the desired database name.